# "No provider for ViewContainerRef" while using ng-packagr component

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have created a components **library** using angular cli **`ng generate library`**,
with a component that uses `*ngIf` inside a module.

After successfully build and install the library in my main project,
when I try to use the component I am getting `No provider for ViewContainerRef` error.

Versions:

@angular/cli version: "~7.0.6",

@angular/* version : "~7.0.0"

Error:

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> ViewContainerRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!

component:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'al-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.scss']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() text: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

template:

```
<div *ngIf="header">

</div>
```

module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CardComponent } from './card.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [CardComponent],
})
export class CardModule { }
```

Comment: It comes from `CommonModule`, be sure to import it correctly.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I am importing the `CommonModule`.

Comment: be sure that you're importing the `CommonModule` into the same Module that you declare the component.

Comment: this is my module:
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [CardComponent],
    imports: [
      CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [CardComponent],
  })
  export class CardModule { }

Comment: are you using `ViewContainerRef` in the Component, or trying to use it in a Service?

Comment: can you please post your constructor? for `CardComponent`

Comment: I am just using a component with `*ngIF` and then try to use this component after build in my main project

Comment: please note that I am using an external library, building and publishing it, and then try to use a simple component from the library that causes this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found out the problem,
it solved by adding `"preserveSymlinks": true` to my main project's angular.json file.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
             ...
```

this is where I have found the solution: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10896

Comment: Not exist for Angluar 8, how do it so ?

Comment: @itay oded it doesn't work on ng serve, any ideas? i think this is the --prod profile

Comment: Works for me with Angular 8 and with ng serve.

Comment: this solved my issue when i was trying to use bti for angular! Thanks